# When I correlated two query results, something unexpected happened！

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I execute the following script with hive：

```
select 
    a.keyno
from
(
    select 
        keyno,
        reportyear
    from hive_ldtmp.tmp_kzz_company_report_people_count_grow_info
    where yeartype=1
    and keyno='00003d22be771b36f27a7be24431e407'
    and reportyear=2019
) a
left join
(
    select 
        keyno,
        reportyear
    from hive_ldtmp.tmp_kzz_company_report_people_count_grow_info
    where yeartype=2
    and keyno='00003d22be771b36f27a7be24431e407'
    and reportyear=2019
) b on a.keyno=b.keyno
and a.reportyear=b.reportyear;
```

The return i get is None：

```
0 results.
```

However, I am sure that when I execute the two queries separately, they have results：

```
    -- a
    select 
        keyno,
        reportyear
    from hive_ldtmp.tmp_kzz_company_report_people_count_grow_info
    where yeartype=1
    and keyno='00003d22be771b36f27a7be24431e407'
    and reportyear=2019;
 
    -- b
    select 
        keyno,
        reportyear
    from hive_ldtmp.tmp_kzz_company_report_people_count_grow_info
    where yeartype=2
    and keyno='00003d22be771b36f27a7be24431e407'
    and reportyear=2019;
```

this is the result(the results of a and b are the same)：

| keyno | year |
| --- | --- |
| 00003d22be771b36f27a7be24431e407 | 2019 |

Than,I changed the format of the table from `ORC` to `Textfile`,
I executed the entire code and it got the result I wanted.

so...?Where is the problem？

Answer (score 1):

In the first query this filter is different `where yeartype=2`. In the query b which you executed separately it is `where yeartype=1`

BTW you can eliminate joining with the same table. Use aggregation and filtering, like in this query:

```
select keyno
from
(
select keyno,
    max(case when reportyear = 1 then keyno else null end) as yr1_keyno,
    max(case when reportyear = 2 then keyno else null end) as yr2_keyno,
    reportyear
from hive_ldtmp.tmp_kzz_company_report_people_count_grow_info
where yeartype in ( 1, 2)
and keyno='00003d22be771b36f27a7be24431e407'
and reportyear=2019
group by keyno, reportyear
)s where yr1_keyno=yr2_keyno --the same as your INNER JOIN (if join does not duplicate rows)
```

Comment: That is my description of the mistake, and I have corrected my description. When I execute query a and query b，their results  are the same。